# How to redirect all pages in folder?

Tags: .htaccess

I have some old pages and I need to redirect them.

**Example:**
I need to redirect from:

```
www.domain.com/en/customer-detail/"customer_name"
```

to:

```
www.domain.com/de/customer-detail/"customer_name"
```

How can I do this?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple redirect in your site root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/en/(customer-detai.*)$ /de/$1
```

Comment: No, it onlx needs to work with: "/customer-detail/"